# Make table header fixed and tbody scrollable (both x and y)

Tags: html, css

I am trying to fixed header (both on top and on left) and allows other rows to scroll. I had find a lot of scroll able tbody table with fixed thead like [here](https://codepen.io/yavuzselim/pen/LNYrBd).

Also, when I tried to implement this code, my table is broken may be because of longer width.

However, I could not find scroll able with respect to x axis keekping header fixed at the same time.

I would appreciate any suggestion to deal with this.

My main requirements:
- top header should be fixed when scrolled vertically
- left header should be fixed when scrolled horizontally.

```css
th{
  background: #c3c3c3
}
.table-fixed {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}
.table-fixed tbody {
  height: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
.table-fixed thead, .table-fixed tbody, .table-fixed tr, .table-fixed td, .table-fixed th {
  display: block;
}
.table-fixed tbody td {
  float: left;
}
.table-fixed thead tr th {
  float: left;
  background-color: #f39c12;
  border-color: #e67e22;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="tableBox">
<table class="table table-bordered table-fixed text-center header-fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr class="fixed-row">
            <th></th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>05</th>
            <th>06</th>
            <th>07</th>
            <th>08</th>
            <th>09</th>
            <th>10</th>
            <th>11</th>
            <th>12</th>
            <th>13</th>
            <th>14</th>
            <th>15</th>
            <th>16</th>
            <th>17</th>
            <th>18</th>
            <th>19</th>
            <th>20</th>
            <th>21</th>
            <th>22</th>
            <th>23</th>
            <th>24</th>
            <th>25</th>
            <th>26</th>
            <th>27</th>
            <th>28</th>
            <th>29</th>
            <th>30</th>
            <th>31</th>
            <th>32</th>
            <th>33</th>
            <th>34</th>
            <th>35</th>
            <th>36</th>
            <th>37</th>
            <th>38</th>
            <th>39</th>
            <th>40</th>
            <th>41</th>
            <th>42</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
       
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>6</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>7</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>8</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
     

    </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```

In case if you prefer to look in codepen: [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/prying/pen/mdbRJMa)

Comment: Did you try this https://jsfiddle.net/RMarsh/bzuasLcz/3/ ?

Comment: the header on the left is just shaking couldn't we make stable that? may be if we go with pure css that might not happen?

Comment: add in your css .fixed-row{position:fixed;}

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer.html

```js
$(function(){
  $("#headerFixed").tableHeadFixer({"left" : 1});
})
```

```css
th{
  background: #c3c3c3
}
    #tableBox {
        max-height: 150px;
    }

    #headerFixed {
        width: 100%;
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-For-Fixed-Table-Header-Footer-Columns-TableHeadFixer/tableHeadFixer.js"></script>




<div class="tableBox">
<table id="headerFixed" class="table table-bordered table-fixed text-center header-fixed">
  <thead>
    <tr class="fixed-row">
            <th></th>
            <th>01</th>
            <th>02</th>
            <th>03</th>
            <th>04</th>
            <th>05</th>
            <th>06</th>
            <th>07</th>
            <th>08</th>
            <th>09</th>
            <th>10</th>
            <th>11</th>
            <th>12</th>
            <th>13</th>
            <th>14</th>
            <th>15</th>
            <th>16</th>
            <th>17</th>
            <th>18</th>
            <th>19</th>
            <th>20</th>
            <th>21</th>
            <th>22</th>
            <th>23</th>
            <th>24</th>
            <th>25</th>
            <th>26</th>
            <th>27</th>
            <th>28</th>
            <th>29</th>
            <th>30</th>
            <th>31</th>
            <th>32</th>
            <th>33</th>
            <th>34</th>
            <th>35</th>
            <th>36</th>
            <th>37</th>
            <th>38</th>
            <th>39</th>
            <th>40</th>
            <th>41</th>
            <th>42</th>
        </tr>
  </thead>
    <tbody>
       
        <tr>
            <th>0</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>2</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>4</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>5</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>6</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>7</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
      <tr>
            <th>8</th>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                95

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                85

            </td>
            <td>
                333

            </td>
            <td>
                530

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                440

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-570</span>

            </td>
            <td>
            430

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                605

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-603</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                245

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-595</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                305

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-115</span>

            </td>
            <td>
                430

            </td>
            <td> 45 </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                395

            </td>
            <td>

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                255

            </td>
            <td>
                270

            </td>
            <td>
                1051

            </td>
            <td>
                220

            </td>
            <td>
                312

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                180

            </td>
            <td>
                45

            </td>
            <td>
                978

            </td>
            <td>
                <span>-99</span>

            </td>
        </tr>
     

    </tbody>

</table>
</div>
```